# Increase storage allocated to Linux directory

Tags: linux, partitioning, storage

I've a challenge I simply can't Google. I manage a Mail server that currently urgently needs more disk space.  The partitioning is as follows;

```
Filesystem       Size    Used   Avail Capacity  Mounted on
/dev/aacd0s1a    143G     51G     80G    39%    /
/dev/aacd0s1e    291G    107G    161G    40%    /var
/dev/aacd2s1     3.0T    2.6T    103G    96%    /mails
/dev/aacd1s1     1.8T    1.4T    176G    89%    /backup
```

Postfix user mails are stored on a second disk under /mails which is currently getting filled up.

If I added another disk say /dev/aacd3s1 as big as 4TB , how would increase the size of /mails so that I've more extra 4TB for /mail directory?

Answer (score 4):

If you want the two drives to be accessible *as if they were one drive* then you're going to need to migrate to LVM (or BTRFS, or something). Logical Volume Management is not a filesystem -- you continue to use the same filesystem you use now, probably ext4 -- but rather it is an advanced form of partition management. Advantages include the ability to form partitions from non-contiguous fragments of free diskspace, and -- crucially for you -- the ability to have a partition that spans multiple devices. (If you really get into it you can make snapshots that allow taking backups without pausing services, and sharing free space between multiple logical partitions, but that maybe going too far, in this case.)

There's a tool called [blocks](https://github.com/g2p/blocks) that can convert an existing ext4 partition into an LVM-wrapped ext4 partition, in place. (Do a dry run somewhere else, and back up your data before doing anything on the real system!)

If that's successful you have to rewrite your fstab to use the LVM name for the new "logical volume". If you mounted your partitions by UUID or label, rather than device name, then you might have nothing to do.

Once your existing disk is using LVM you can set up your new disk with LVM, add them both to the same volume-group, and then simply extend your existing partition across both drives as a single LVM logical volume.

`df` should then say something like this:

```
Filesystem               Size    Used   Avail Capacity  Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg0-mails    7.0T    2.6T    4.1T    37%    /mails
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this same issue and needed to do this to my /opt drive and apparently this happens quite frequently. What you're going to need to do is add the new drive, move the existing information back and then create symlinks back.

Using /opt as a example

Make a new mount point for the new /opt:

```
mkdir /mnt/newopt
```

Mount it to the required partition (to be shared with /usr)

```
mount /dev/hdb5 /mnt/newopt
```

Move the old /opt files to /newopt

```
cd /opt
cp -ax * /mnt/newopt
```

Backup the old /opt just in case - once everything is ok can delete

```
cd /
cp opt opt.old
```

Create the symlinks so that Linux and software can find the /opt files

```
cd /
ln -s /mnt/newopt /opt
```

Edit /etc/fstab to reflect changes

```
/dev/hdb5 /opt ext2 defaults 1 2
```

Reboot.

Just google for moving /opt to new drive as there are TONS of guides all over the internet for that. You're just replacing your /opt with /mail.

Comment: That's a good way to get the new drive to _replace_ the space on the old drive, but it won't _add_ it as additional space to the directory.  For example, if your first drive is 2TB, and you mount /opt or /mail on a new 4TB drive, then yes 4TB is better than 2TB.  But you won't get 6TB for that directory.  If you want all the space shared, so you could get 6TB in the example, you need LVM or BTRFS like in the answer from "ams" above.

Comment: You're absolutely correct about LVM for extending the drive. I should have read the question better. Reading your response and rereading the question, an LVM solution is correct.

Comment: Thanks @MattKing, I think this could serve as a short-term solution. LVM is certainly a more promising solution